# About The switch Statement in Java

Tags: java

I'm still learning. Today I have a question in SoloLearn, into The switch Statement lesion:

```
int day = 3;

switch(day) {
  case 1:
    System.out.println("Monday");
    break;
  case 2:
    System.out.println("Tuesday");
    break;
  case 3:
    System.out.println("Wednesday");
    break;

// Outputs "Wednesday"
```

and I thinks, I can have a example to remember about input and switch Statement: I want input a number, and 1 as Monday, 2 as Tuesday.... to 7 as Sunday, and repeat: 8 as Monday, 9 as Tuesday....
This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner day = new Scanner(System.in);


        if (day.nextInt()>7){
            day.nextInt()=day.nextInt()%7;
        }

    switch(day.nextInt()){
        case 1 :
            System.out.println("Monday");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Tuesday");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Wednesday");
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("Thursday");
            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.println("Friday");
            break;
        case 6: 
            System.out.println("Saturday");
            break;
        case 0: 
            System.out.println("Sunday");
        case 7:
            System.out.println("Sunday");
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

and error. My knowledge's not enough to fix this thing (I think so, because i'm a newbie and still learning). Can you expand for me, fix this thing and thanks for teach!
Have fun!

Answer (score 5):

The problem is here:

```
    if (day.nextInt()>7){
        day.nextInt()=day.nextInt()%7;
    }
```

You're trying to assign a value back to the method call `day.nextInt()`, which you can't do. Instead, try something like the following:

```
int dayNum = day.nextInt() % 7;
```

Also, your `switch` includes a case for `dayNum == 7`, which will never be the case.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand.
Last time, I tried to add

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @kolosy You are missing a break statement below `case 0` and by writing `day.nextInt()` four times, you are actually asking the user to enter four times.
Also you cant `day.nextInt()=day.nextInt()%7;` do this. By doing it you're trying to assign a value back to the method call Change your code of `main` function to this

```
        Scanner day = new Scanner(System.in);
        int enteredDay = day.nextInt();

        if (enteredDay > 7) {
            enteredDay = enteredDay % 7;
        }

        switch (enteredDay) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Monday");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Tuesday");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Wednesday");
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("Thursday");
            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.println("Friday");
            break;
        case 6:
            System.out.println("Saturday");
            break;
        case 0:
            System.out.println("Sunday");
            break;
        case 7:
            System.out.println("Sunday");
            break;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a break statement below `case 0`. Java does not allow label fall-through like some other languages.

Also - you should be checking for your number being >= 7, not >7, or you'll never get a 0 on the second week. 8 % 7 is 1

Comment: ..\Playground\:9: error: unexpected type
                day.nextInt()=day.nextInt()%7;
                           ^
  required: variable
  found:    value
1 error


This is error in SoloLearn. can you expland for me?

Answer (score 0):

Add break after case 0:

```
            case 6: 
                System.out.println("Saturday");
                break;
            case 0: 
                System.out.println("Sunday");
              break;
```

If the value in switch() goes beyond 7 than you will get error as you have not provided any `default case` here. You can either do something like `number%7`to get the value always in case range.

Answer (score 0):

NextInt() is a method .. you can't assign it a value

Answer (score 0):

You need to use nextInt() once to get the input and store it in a variable. Every time you call nextInt() it would look for the next integer value entered.

```
Scanner day = new Scanner(System.in);

int dayInput = day.nextInt();
    if (dayInput>7){
        dayInput=dayInput%7;
    }

switch(dayInput){
    case 1 :
        System.out.println("Monday");
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Tuesday");
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("Wednesday");
        break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println("Thursday");
        break;
    case 5:
        System.out.println("Friday");
        break;
    case 6: 
        System.out.println("Saturday");
        break;
    case 0: 
        System.out.println("Sunday");
    case 7:
        System.out.println("Sunday");
        break;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by creating an `int` value to set the input for `day` as `day.nextInt()` then you can do the math in the created variable and make the switch depending on that value, this should work:

```
   Scanner day = new Scanner(System.in);
    int dayVal = day.nextInt();

    if (dayVal>7){
        dayVal %= 7;
    }

    switch(dayVal){
        case 1 :
        System.out.println("Monday");
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Tuesday");
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("Wednesday");
        break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println("Thursday");
        break;
    case 5:
        System.out.println("Friday");
        break;
    case 6:
        System.out.println("Saturday");
        break;
    case 0:
        System.out.println("Sunday");
        break;
    }
}
```

As said before, you need to change 7 to 0 because you will never have a residue of 0, therefore you will never get a Sunday